# Prestashop 1.7 Override CmsController

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.7, visual-composer

In prestashop v1.7.4.2, with VisualComposer installed,
after I bought another module named: FormBuilder, can't enable and cause error like this:

> Cannot enable module gformbuilderpro. Unable to install override: The
>   method initContent in the class CmsController is already overridden by
>   the module jscomposer version 4.4.7 at 2018-08-25 18:20:10 .

any knowledge or instruction to solve this conflict?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op5it.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 override:

1- jscomposer => override => cmsController => initContent

2- gformbuilderpro => override => cmsController => initContent

Second method has conflict with first method

Solution:

1- remove initContent method from gformbuilderpro module

2- merge content of both initContent methods on this path :

```
root/override/controllers/front/CmsController.php
```

3- install gformbuilderpro module and enjoy PrestaShop

!!!! It's better to put new merged initContent method on jscomposer for future changes